# Converting "August 2012" to DateTime object with TryParseExact

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, tryparse

I am trying to parse a string that is of the format "August 2012" into a DateTime object. The string is coming from the column name in a DataTable.

```
string columnName= row[col].ToString(); // "August 2012"
```

Initially I tried using DateTime.TryParse() ...

```
bool result = DateTime.TryParse(row[col].ToString, out convertedDateTime);
```

but it kept returning false. So next I tried using DateTime.TryParseExact using the the proper cultureformat as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#YearMonth) ...

```
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("af-ZA");
DateTime.TryParseExact(row[col].ToString(), "y", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out columnNameAsDate)
```

However, this keep returning false also. What am I doing wrong? SHouldn't I be able to parse a string in the format **August 2012** into a DateTime object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you the date expected.

```
string columnName= row[col].ToString();  // ==> August 2012
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime.TryParseExact(columnName, "MMMM yyyy", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out columnNameAsDate);
```

First: You should specify the exact culture. In `af-ZA` culture the eighth month of the year is named "Augustus" not "August" and this will, of course, fail.

Second: You should pass the correct format specification to get the full month name (MMMM) and the year (yyyy).

Answer (score 0):

I would split the string first:

```
DateTime outDate = new DateTime();
string[] words = columnName.Split(' ');
if(words.Length>1){
   string month = words[0].Substring(0,3);
   string year = words[1];
   outDate = DateTime.ParseExact(month+' '+year, 
   "MMM yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```